# Can we create a dynamic folder name along with date function is ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a folder in ADLS which will look like below:
TableName/Year/MM/DD
where Table Name will be inserted in Dataset while running the pipeline.
Getting below folder name while trying this scenario:
**landling / body('Copy data1ComposeRuntimeVariables')?.AzureFolderNameGeneric284c15f2e78d4e1caca220b0f4467e86.FolderName**

After that date folders are getting created.

Code in parametrization :
**dataset().FolderName/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd')}**

Folder name expected below (TableName-Product)
Product/2023/10/24

Comment: can you pls post some images and the json being used?

Answer (score 0):

Result folders like above will be created when you are giving the above expression `dataset().FolderName/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd')}` in the Dataset folder path.

[image]

[image]

To achieve your requirement, follow the below steps.

As you are passing the Table Name and date, create two dataset parameters. one for the Table name and another for the date folders.

[image]

Use these two in the Dataset folder path like below.

```
@concat(dataset().FolderName,'/',dataset().Dates)
```

[image]

Now, in the pipeline, pass your table name and the date dynamic content to these parameters.

```
@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd')}
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]